# Unable to delete when using soft delete

Tags: authentication, controller, laravel-5.1, soft-delete, laravel-blade

Trying out softdelete and I'm yet to understand what is wrong with the code. Whenever I try deleting. it doesn't, it throws back the page at me.

This is the controller for confirmation page before deleting:

```
public function deleteView($id)
    {
        $company = Company::find($id);
        return view('company.show')->with('company', $company);
    }
```

This is the view to confirm before deleting:

```
@extends('layouts.member')

    @section('content')
        {!! Form::open(array('action'=> array('CompanyController@destroy', $company->id, '_method'=>'delete'))) !!}
        {!! Form::token() !!}

            <p>{!! $company->companyname !!}</p>
            <p>{!! $company->companyaddress !!}</p>
            </p>{!! $company->country !!}</p>
            <p>{!! $company->state !!}</p>
            <p>{!! $company->email !!}</p>
            <p>{!! $company->phone !!}</p>
            <p>{!! $company->website !!}</p>
            <p>{!! $company->companytype !!}</p>

            {!! Form::hidden('company_id', $company->id) !!}
            <p>{!! Form::submit('DELETE') !!}</p>
        {!! Form::close() !!}
    @stop
```

This is the controller to effect deleting:

```
public function destroy(CompanyRequest $companyRequest)
    {
        $company_id = $companyRequest->company_id;
        if(!$this->companyBelongsToUser($company_id))
        {
            return redirect()->route('companyindex', $company_id)->with('message', 'Sorry, yuo cannot delete this company');
        }else
        {
            $company = Company::findOrFail($company_id);
            $company->delete();

            return redirect()->route('companyindex', $company_id)->with('message', 'Company deleted successfully');
        }
    }
```

This is the route to return the confirmation page before deleting:

```
Route::get('delete/{id}', array('as'=>'deleteView', 'uses'=>'CompanyController@deleteView'));
```

This is the route for actual deleting:

```
Route::delete('deletecompany/{id}', array('as'=>'deleteCompany', 'uses'=>'CompanyController@destroy'));
```

This is the function to check if the user is the expected user.

```
private function companyBelongsToUser($id){
        $company = Company::find($id);
        if($company->user_id == Auth::user()->id){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: what do you mean by "throws back the page at me"? what error you getting?

Comment: No error message, just returns the page.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got it solved. The primary problem was that I was trying to retrieve the the id of the company at runtime which was not available.

To my surprise, Laravel already cares for the thing I was trying to do manually, all I did is to pass in the a generic id, and Laravel figured out which company I'm trying to query, and does the job.

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
        $company = Company::findOrFail($id);
        if(!$company->user_id === Auth::user()->id)
        {
            return redirect()->route('companyindex')->with('message', 'Sorry, you cannot delete this company');
        }else{
            $company->delete();
            return redirect()->route('companyindex')->with('message', 'Company successfully deleted.');
        }
    }
```